# How to rewrite url by removing controller name in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, routes, url-routing

I have my urls like:

samplesite.com/aboutus [aboutus is controller]

samplesite.com/contactus [contactus is controller]

Also I have registered members that are shown as

samplesite.com/memberaccount/32 [memberaccount is controller and 32 is memberid]

I have also done rewriting on the above urls for members to be shown as

samplesite.com/memberaccount/john [john is the member with memberid 32]

What I want to achieve is this:

http://www.samplesite.com/john (this is causing problem as it clashes with the controller names aboutus, contactus etc.. and let me tell you I have 40 to 50 such controllers. Please can anyone suggest how do I get this.

Comment: You need to post your routes.php. You might find it tricky to achieve this using codeigniters routing as you would need to create a catch all route to redirect anything to your members controller. This would need to be placed at the bottom of your routes.php. It may be better to re-write the URL to remove the memberaccount segment in your `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

for this thing you have use the routes in ci
which are as given

```php
$route['aboutus'] = "any controller is map to that name";
```

> samplesite.com/aboutus [aboutus is controller]
>   samplesite.com/contactus [contactus is controller]

```php
$route['memberaccount/(:num)'] = "any controller is map to that name/$1";
```

> samplesite.com/memberaccount/32

if still not getting try the above link
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: $route['(:any)'] = "memberaccount/$1"; this works for me.. so when I go to samplesite.com/john it maps to samplesite.com/memberaccount/john.. 

but it gives problem when I try to go to my aboutus page. ie, samplesite.com/aboutus .. it treats aboutus as one of the member on the site. and tries to map it to samplesite.com/memberaccount/aboutus and that is what I precisely want to avoid.. is there now way where I can make routes ignore the controller files. The other workaround would be to list all the controllers as 

$route['aboutus'] = "aboutus"; etc.. I have 60 controllers files